# How to get full geo location details using user input in html/html5?

Tags: javascript, android, html, geolocation

In android I could use google play services and geo location functions to get a user to type a string like "London, England" or "McDonalds" etc.., and have the service take that string and return a set of Location Objects. Each one has a city,address,country,lat,long etc... details.

I'm now making a web app version of it and I want to know if its possible to do this in HTML/html5 with any plugins preferable by trusted companies like Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to question if you even looked ;)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

The Maps service was born on the web, of course that exists!

Comment: But I don't see the specific part that takes a string and converts it to a list of location objects? Also do I even need an api key, I was using google map api v3 (with jquery plugin) without using a key and I could see the map...

Comment: @omega  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

you send it a request of your address and it returns matches that could be what you're looking for.